# Angular with Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, angularjs

I want to use `Angular` for a feature in `Magento2` E-commerce website.

**For Ex :** - I want to create a page(`MoodBoard`) where customer can create a look using drag drop.

I have created a new module for it.

Now I need to implement Angular in this module.

How do I do that?

Comment: You are talking abt angular.js v.1?

Comment: I am working with AngularJS v1.7.9 but I don't mind if you give me solution related to another version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Angular 1.6.6 in one of my custom builds.
you can follow this layout way to include the angularJs It will also add ng-app & ng-controller attributes to the body tag.

**your_custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Custom_Module::js/angular.js"/> 
        <link src="Custom_Module::js/angular-filter.min.js"/> 
        <link src="Custom_Module::js/mycustom.js"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- this will add an attribute to body class -->
        <attribute name='ng-app' value='myApp'/>
        <attribute name='ng-controller' value="myController" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**mycustom.js** > In this file I have code for angular based logic.